# Two questions about Disqus

Tags: html, css, tumblr, disqus

I have a quick question regarding two parts of Disqus that are bugging me and causing aesthetic problems on my site.

The first is that at the top of each of my posts on the main page of my blog, Disqus flashes 'comments' very quickly and then disappears. I went into Disqus settings, turned off Disqus 2013 features and disabled the number of comments being shown in the settings, which worked, but unfortunately I see the 'comments' title flash very quickly.

The second is that, if you click each individual post, the disqus loading bar pops up on the right-hand side, often over the picture that is a focal point of my text posts. It just looks ugly, and I'd like to fix it.

For reference, my site is [Draftdaybust.com](http://www.draftdaybust.com)

Any help would be greatly appreciated; I'll also say that I really don't know much about HTML or building websites, I'm just kind of doing my best to get by and make a decent looking blog. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's happening and how to fix it...

**Problem 1**

By default, the word 'comments' is coded into your page. When you removed the text from the Disqus settings, that only fires once the Disqus comment count javascript loads. There's a short delay between when your page HTML renders and when that javascript loads, thus you get the "flash". If you prefer to not have a comment counter at all you should remove the following from your theme (it might look slightly different in your theme):

`<div style="font-size: 10px; text-align: left;"><a class="dsq-comment-count" href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread">Comments</a></div>`

Additionally you should remove the comment counting javascript so the site doesn't load any unnecessary resources:

> 

```
<script type="text/javascript">var disqus_url = ""; var disqus_title ="";</script><script type="text/javascript">
var disqus_shortname = 'draftdaybust';
(function () {
  var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
  s.src = 'http://draftdaybust.disqus.com/count.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
}());
</script>
```

**Problem 2**

Upgrade to Disqus 2012 again. The old version of Disqus renders HTML content onto your page, so it's subject to the whims of your CSS stylesheet (which is what's causing it to start rendering up there). Disqus 2012 uses an iframe that's insulated from conflicting styles.

The original reason for downgrading is made moot by the solution to problem #1.